# Aggregating rows from table2 to avoid duplicating rows from table 1

Tags: sql, database

I am trying to combine two tables - one with item entries and one with value entries. The table with item entries only contain one entry number, whereas the table with value entries contain more entries per item entry. So its a one to many relationship.

When I join the two tables, SQL gives me duplicate rows for every value entry.
(Item entry no. far left, value entry no. far right)

```
**3788138** | 28-CEN | 1 | 13.991,1 | **5223372**
**3788138** | 28-CEN | 1 | 0 | **5010790**
**3788138** | 28-CEN | 1 | 0,06 | **6236002**
```

What I want to do is making one item entry, where I sum the value entries.

```
**3788138** | 28-CEN | 1 | **13.991,16**
```

My SQL statement looks like this:

```
SELECT ILE.[Entry No_] as 'Varepostløbenr.', ILE.[Posting Date], ILE.[Document No_], ILE.[Location Code], ILE.[Invoiced Quantity], ILE.[Remaining Quantity], ILE.[Positive], ILE.[Open], ILE.[Item No_], VE.[Cost posted to G_L], VE.[Entry No_] as 'Værdipostløbenr.'
FROM [VVS Eksperten AS Salg$Item Ledger Entry] AS ILE JOIN
     [VVS Eksperten AS Salg$Value Entry] AS VE
     ON ILE.[Entry No_] = VE.[Item Ledger Entry No_]
```

Hope someone can help me out :-)

Comment: Your query has nothing to do with your sample data (just count the columns).  I would suggest you fix the questions.

Comment: Hi Gordon,
The other columns in my statement are not relevant in my question. Therefore I haven't included them in the example.

Comment: please update your question with the schema of the two tables and reduce the query to the relevant part of the tables to make it more readable

Comment: You say you want to sum values. Check out `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically what you want to do is to

```
SELECT col_1, col_2..col_n, SUM(value_column)

...

GROUP BY(col_1, col_2..col_n)
```

Comment: It worked using group by.. fantastic! Thank you very much for the help.